# How to retrieve Work Item linked to specific commit - Azure Devops REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to be able to retrieve the linked work item of any given specific commit. I'm currently using the following api call

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=5.0
```

with the following response

```
{
  "parents": [],
  "treeId": "7fa1a3523ffef51c525ea476bffff7d648b8cb3d",
  "push": {
    "pushedBy": {
      "id": "8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
      "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
      "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
      "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
      "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d"
    },
    "pushId": 1,
    "date": "2014-01-29T23:33:15.2434002Z"
  },
  "commitId": "be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4",
  "author": {
    "name": "Chuck Reinhart",
    "email": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
    "date": "2014-01-29T23:32:09Z"
  },
  "committer": {
    "name": "Chuck Reinhart",
    "email": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
    "date": "2014-01-29T23:32:09Z"
  },
  "comment": "First cut\n",
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4",
  "remoteUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/commit/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4"
    },
    "repository": {
      "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249"
    },
    "changes": {
      "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4/changes"
    },
    "web": {
      "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/commit/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4"
    },
    "tree": {
      "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/trees/7fa1a3523ffef51c525ea476bffff7d648b8cb3d"
    }
  }
}
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 and am missing a way to see what work item its linked to or if it is linked at all. Does anyone know of a way to get this information? Thanks

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I tried the method in the answer and am still unsure about it. See the comment on the answer for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Get Commits` API, [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). The base request looks like:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.0
```

You could then add the following parameters:

- `fromCommitId` - string - *If provided, a lower bound for filtering commits alphabetically*
- `toCommitId` - string - *If provided, an upper bound for filtering commits alphabetically*
- `includeWorkItems` - boolean - *Whether to include linked work items*

So that your final query would look something like, with your toCommitId and fromCommitId parameters being your commit id that you are after (the documentation doesn't specificy whether these are inclusive or exclusive so your might have to tweak this slightly):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?includeWorkItems=true&.toCommitId={searchCriteria.toCommitId}&fromCommitId={searchCriteria.fromCommitId}&api-version=5.0
```

The result should contain a `workItems` property inside each commit object of the response as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitcommitref).

**Note:**

> Parameters that use the searchCriteria prefix in their name can be specified without it as query parameters, e.g. searchCriteria.$top -> $top

---

**There is also**:

- `ids` - array - *If provided, specifies the exact commit ids of the commits to fetch. May not be combined with other parameters.*

Which *could* allow you to forgo passing in the to and from commit ids but the docs state that it **May not be combined with other parameters** - even though the example request *does* combine it with other parameters. I haven't tried this myself so please do comment when you find out whether you go with from-to id or just ids.

---

**OPs action**

The OP ended up using the following request as they didn't mind all commits being returned:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?includeWorkItems=true&api-version=5.0
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I ran `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?includeWorkItems=true&api-version=5.0` and the response included the following fields for each commit: commitId, author,committer, comment, changeCounts, url, remoteUrl. Is this correct? Not sure where to access workItems from here.

Comment: @kg123 there should be a ‘workItems’ property inside each commit object of the response as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitcommitref).

Comment: No problem @kg123 would you mind commenting which method you used e.g. 1) `fromCommitId` and `toCommitId` with `includeWorkItems` and specifying whether you passed the same commit id for the to and from values, or 2) `ids` parameter with the exact commit id as the value along with `includeWorkItems`. Then I can update my answer to be more useful to the community. :-)

Comment: Sure, I used the first method only including `includeWorkItems` and excluding the parameters `fromCommitId` and `toCommitId` to get all commits with their related work items included.

Comment: having jut tried, the `includeworkitems` does not work in combination with the `ids`, but does with `fromCommitId` and `toCommitId`

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps the work items associated to a specific commit can be found on the following page:

```
https://{instance}/{team-project}/_git/{repository}/commit/{commitId}?tab=details
```

These are obtained via [Artifact Uri Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/artifact-uri-query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#query-work-items-for-artifacts).

Here is an example from the Azure DevOps REST API documentation:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/artifacturiquery?api-version=7.0

{
  "artifactUris": [
    "vstfs:///Git/Commit/3065bb47-8344-4370-982a-5183abf197fa%2F649107bd-ab35-4192-8584-601f64172f80%2F4800cfa0be564b1e606d6811e99e0380f765a9c4"
  ]
}
```

The request contains a list of artifact URIs (in this case commit artifacts) to use for querying linked work items. An artifact URI for commits is defined in the following format:

```
vstfs:///Git/Commit/{projectId}%2F{repositoryId}%2F{commitId}
```

The response includes the work items linked to all the commits provided in the `artifactUris` array.